# Alternative measures for the unit interval

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is there a way to construct a measure for the unit interval such that:

1. For the Borel sets, the measure is countably additive, translation invariant, and equal to the length of the set
2. For the other sets, the measure is still countably additive, but not necessarily translation invariant

Comment: A measure on what sigma-algebra of subsets of $[0,1]$? The Lebesgue measure satisfies (1) and (2) and is even translation invariant!

Comment: If you have in mind defining a measure on _every_ subset of $[0,1]$, then you will want to look into measurable cardinals. [Here](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/rvmc.pdf) is an excellent treatment by Fremlin.

Comment: To be honest, the source you have given goes a bit above my head, but is it correct to say that we need to impose a new axiom (ie the existence of a measurable cardinal) in order to construct a measure that satisfies (1) and (2)?

Comment: You didn't answer my first question about the sigma-algebra, which is crucial.

Comment: Oh, I'm talking about a measure on all subsets of the unit interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are asking about measures defined on every subset of $[0,1]$. As I pointed out in my comment, if the question is "Does there exist a sigma-algebra extending the Borel algebra for which (1) and (2) hold?", then an affirmative answer is witnessed by the Lebesgue measure.

Ulam showed that there is an extension of the Lebesgue measure to every subset of $[0,1]$ if and only if there exists an atomlessly-measurable cardinal, and that atomlessly-measurable cardinals are weakly inaccessible (this is 1D in the Fremlin paper).

Moreover, if ZFC is consistent, then so is ZFC + "there does not exist a weakly inaccessible cardinal". So ZFC cannot prove that there is an extension of the Lebesgue measure to every subset of $[0,1]$ (unless it is inconsistent).

So, in order to answer your question in the affirmative, we need axioms beyond ZFC or we need to assume that ZFC is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Hmm, this gives me quite a few philosophical questions about probability...

Comment: @user253846 Would love to hear what they are if you care to post them here (if they have some mathematical content) or in the philosophy SE.